# What goes in Target field of dialog for creating a branch?

Tags: azure-devops, branch, tfvc

Before I started using VSTS I had my source code in
C:\Users\jjacobs\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\BigSolution
And a branch version with some newer code in
C:\0JQJ\CS2017\BigSolution.

Years ago I was using Visual Source Safe and really liked it. Very easy to use. VSTS is very very different from what I remember about VSS.
After a very steep learning curve and agonizing hours I put the main version in VSTS. Now I need to create a VSTS branch with the source code from C:\0JQJ\CS2017\BigSolution.

I opened Source Control Explorer, right-clicked BigSolution, selected Branching and Merging > Branch. In the dialog, for Target I typed in C:\0JQJ\CS2017\BigSolution, but it did not like that.
What should I type there? Will there be a later dialog where I can put in the path to the source code I want in the branch?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it did not like that"? What is the **exact** error message you got?

Comment: It said the path has to start with $, which was totally confusing. Your answer clarified that.

Comment: @JonJacobs After creating a branch, you need to copy files from C:\0JQJ\CS2017\BigSolution to the TFVC branch mapped firectory, and then add the files in source control. Finally checkin the changes.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Thank you. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target should be a branch name (any name you'd like), **relative to source control**, not a location on your computer.

Ex: `$/MyTeamProjectName/MyBranch`

`$` indicates the root of your team project collection.

`MyTeamProjectName` is the name of the team project containing your code -- you cannot branch a team project.

`MyBranch` is the name of the branch you want to create. This can be nested more deeply: `$/MyTeamProjectName/Development/SomeFeatureBranch` will create a branch named `SomeFeatureBranch` under a `Development` folder.

Remember, creating a branch in TFVC is a **server** operation. It has no bearing on where source code is located on your PC.

Comment: Thank you, that helps, but I am not all the way there. Eventually I came to the conclusion that I must create a project with the name of the branch. Then it let me proceed. I entered the path to the source code when asked, and I got this error: TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/OptimaxxScanBranch.  Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one. Well, I had already done that. i tried again and received the same error. What do I do now?

Comment: @JonJacobs Like I said, you can't branch the team project root. You have to create a folder to serve as your trunk, put the source code inside that, then create a branch from that folder. The TFVC convention is to call the trunk branch `main`, but you can call it whatever you'd like.

Comment: This may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=vsts